# How to uncolor a layer without losing its content in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

During my design on Photoshop I have filled a layer with black and used a white brush on it. But I want my background to be transparent. How can I decolorize my layer's background without losing its content?

Comment: By "decolorize" do you mean to eliminate the black fill you applied to the layer before starting to draw with white? That will result in your white drawing showing on a transparent background, is that correct?

Comment: @ACEkin Yes I man that.

Comment: There seems to be a satisfactory answer that was accepted, no need for another answer at this point. But, the way a question is formulated affects the answers it will receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the Channels palette and click the dotted circle at the bottom ("Load channel as selection").

Then from the "Layer" menu, choose `New Fill Layer >`  `Solid Color...` and pick a foreground colour. A new layer is created and the selection added to it as a mask.

Turn off all other layers to reveal a transparent background.

If you find that you would like to reverse the transparent areas with the inked areas, select the layer mask in the layers palette and click `Image` menu, `Adjustments >` `Invert`.